# Woocommerce product variations without using javascript

Tags: javascript, wordpress, woocommerce

Is it possible to have a fall back method for Woocommerce product variations for users without javascript?

The checkout page has a paragraph about not having javascript enabled with a warning message. The product variations don't display any warning message and they simply don't work.

I realize that while most users have javascript enabled, some don't for one reason or another and I need to at the very least notify them. However, I would rather have a fall back method for users without javascript.

Would it be possible to just show all the variations with their individual add to cart buttons for users without javascript?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this by using a plugin. Google this: eps-variations-add-to-cart.